# Pandora Source Code Lines 2918-2924 definition

Tags: html, google-chrome, pandora

This is from the Pandora One Source Code **Lines 2918-2924**
(view-source:http://www.pandora.com/) on Google Chrome

```
<script id="audioQualityUpsaleTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div class="upsale_container clearfix">
        <h2>Enjoy Higher Quality Audio</h2>

        <p>When Listening on the web, experience music at 192K bits per second. <br/>More bits means
            better sounding Audio.
        </p>

        <div id="audioSample">
            <object width="236" height="35">
                <param value="high" name="quality">
                <param value="transparent" name="wmode">
                <param value="always" name="allowScriptAccess">
                <param value="/static/pandora_one/flash/pandoraone_sampler.swf" name="movie">
                <embed width="236" height="35" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="transparent"
                       src="/static/pandora_one/flash/pandoraone_sampler.swf">
            </object>
        </div>
        {{tmpl "#upgradeForUpsaleTmpl"}}
    </div>
</script>
```

Can someone please explain to me what this section of code is designed to do?

Thank you

Comment: Please copy the lines you're interested in getting an explanation of into your question.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a template for a javascript templating engine (it seems to be jquery based, however I'm not familar with it). You can tell this from the type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" tag.

Templates are often defined within script tags like this (with a type tag that is not javascript declared) because they are not rendered by the browser on page load, however are not executed as javascript. This allows the text to be selected client side, via something like $('#my-template'), and used as a template.